# Open CHM topic with relative path

Tags: chm

Let's say you have a regular HTML file on your local system that has a link to a topic in a CHM file:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
<body>
<a href="mk:@MSITStore:C:\absolute\path\to\chmfile.chm::/path/to/topic.html">chm</a>
</body>
</html>
```

This works, but how do you make the same link work with a relative path to the CHM file rather than an absolute?

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
<body>
<a href="mk:@MSITStore:..\relative\path\to\chmfile.chm::/path/to/topic.html">chm</a>
</body>
</html>
```

This does not work.  Is there a way to build this URI to use a relative path to the CHM file and open a specific topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short story - NO, the complete local path must be specified.

HTML Help 1.x does not have the capability of delivering compressed help over http. You can point to a .chm on the user's local drive, and you can link to a .chm for download, but that's as far as it goes.

The ability to look inside an ITS (CHM) file is something unique to Microsoft Internet Explorer only. Only Internet Explorer (NOT Microsoft Edge browser) could load a locally path like:

```
ms-its:D:\_temp\CHM-example.chm::/garden/garden.htm
```

[image]

The `mk:@MSITStore` protocol works with IE3 and above while `ms-its` works with IE4 and above. A shorter version of `ms-its` is to just use `its`.

Please remember old MS-DOS and the todays Windows 10 Keyboard Shortcuts and Run Commands. Please note this is HH.exe related only and a shortened path is working here only.

<kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>:

[image]

For use with HH.exe you can omit the path to the *.CHM file only, if it is in the %\Windows\Help directory or registered under the following key in the Windows registry:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\HTML Help

[image]

BUT - this fails as expected by using from a HTML file as said above.